# Reading a forwarded message

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Is there a way to get list of IDs (or messages directly) which have been forwarded in some thread? I've been trying to access `attachment` column in FQL table but it doesn't contain anything. I've been trying to search for some kind of answer to this for a while but haven't found anything that would help me. I'm currently using this FQL query:

```
SELECT attachment,message_id,author_id,body,created_time FROM message WHERE thread_id = ID
```

Is there a way to get forwarded messages from `message` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the actual (and old) `message` table won't let you access to the forwarding information. Indeed, the forwarding system looks quite new.

However, you'll soon be able to work with it when the new [unified_message](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/unified_message) table will be available. I guess these `unified_` tables are still not entirely deployed. But you can already use them as development and test purposes.

> Please note: We are in the process of making the new messages system
>   available to all users, at which point this table will replace the
>   existing message table. We are providing early access to this API for
>   registered developer accounts only until the new messaging system is
>   broadly available. You should use the message table for production
>   applications at the current time.